# MongoDb aggregate by embeded document

Tags: mongodb

Im trying to get grouped / aggregated result in Mongodb.

This is how my collection looks like:

```
Array(
[_id] => 529474f4adcc2bb25b662f2f
[lists] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [_id] => 529466c8adcc2b5a5b662f13
                [name] => List 4
                [status] => active
                [changed_at] => 1385460980
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [_id] => 529466c8adcc2b5a5b662f12
                [name] => List 3
                [status] => inactive
                [changed_at] => 1385460980
            )

    )

[name] => Name 20)
```

I want to get a result which will count inactive users grouped by month based on `changed_at`.

I can get results like this way:

```
$ops = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array(
            'lists.status' => 'inactive'
        )
    )   
);
$unsubYearStats = $c->aggregate($ops);
```

The question is how can i use `$group` to group by matched element? (in this case by List's 3 "changed_at" field)

Something like:

```
'$group' => array(
    "_id" => array("month" => array('$month' => '-->$matched_subdocument.changed_at<--')),
    "total" => array('$sum' => 1),
),
```

Thanks for any advices.

Comment: Can you please either use JSON syntax for MongoDB objects in your examples or add a tag for the programming language you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As parvin pointed, the $unwind operator is the right approach.

Here is my query:

```
$ops = array(
            array(
                    '$unwind' => '$lists'
            ),
            array(
                    '$match' => array(
                            "lists.status" => 'active',
                    ),
            ),
            array(
                    '$group' => array(
                            "_id" => array("month" => array('$month' => '$lists.changed_at'), "year" => array('$year' => '$lists.changed_at')),
                            "total" => array('$sum' => 1),
                    ),
            ),
    );
```

First $unwind, then $match and then $group.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) to find the inactive users before grouping.

Query should be something like :

```
db.myObject.aggregate(
  {$unwind : "$lists"},
  {$match : {"lists.status" : "inactive"}},
  {$group : /* write group query here*/}
);
```

Comment: Thats what i am doing. But i need to group by `lists.changed_at`. As you can see there are multiple embeded documents and i need to merge by the field `changed_at` in matched document.

Comment: You can check $unwind operator. This should solve your problem.

Comment: This seems to be a good direction... I will answer my question then.